# A Particular Image on a div not showing in localhost using ASP.net/IIS

Tags: asp.net, css, master-pages

Problem when i run it in localhost my header disappear, sometimes when i'm changing some code in `#header` it appears in design view but when run on localhost it's appearing as a big image and not following the correct height and width that i declare. the code that i will paste here is the one that is not showing either on design view and localhost.

Here is my Masterpage code:

```
<%@ Master Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeFile="MasterPage.master.cs" Inherits="MasterPage" %>

<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head id="Head1" runat="server">
    <title>Untitled Page</title>
    <link href="App_Themes/default/default.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" runat="server" />
    <asp:ContentPlaceHolder id="head" runat="server">
    </asp:ContentPlaceHolder>
</head>
<body>
    <form id="form1" runat="server">
    <div>
    <!--start of css div-->
    <div id="outer">

    <div id="upbg"></div>

    <div id="inner">

        <div id="header" runat="server">

        </div>

        <!--<div id="splash"></div>-->

        <div id="menu">
            <ul>
                <li class="first"><a href="Default.aspx">Home</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Gallery</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Links</a></li>
                <li><a href="About.aspx">About</a></li>
                <li><a href="Contact.aspx">Contact</a></li>
            </ul>

        <div id="Login"><asp:LoginView ID="HeadLoginView" runat="server" EnableViewState="false">
                    <AnonymousTemplate>
                        [ <a href="~/Account/Login.aspx" ID="HeadLoginStatus" runat="server">Log In</a> ]
                    </AnonymousTemplate>
                    <LoggedInTemplate>
                        Welcome <span class="bold"><asp:LoginName ID="HeadLoginName" runat="server" /></span>!
                        [ <asp:LoginStatus ID="HeadLoginStatus" runat="server" LogoutAction="Redirect" LogoutText="Log Out" LogoutPageUrl="~/"/> ]
                    </LoggedInTemplate>
                </asp:LoginView>   </div>
        </div>

<asp:ContentPlaceHolder id="ContentPlaceHolder1" runat="server">

        </asp:ContentPlaceHolder>
        <asp:ContentPlaceHolder id="ContentPlaceHolder2" runat="server">

        </asp:ContentPlaceHolder>


        <div id="footer">

            &copy;Copyright © 2011 My Personal Werbsite. design by Migs Yandoc.

        </div>

    </div>

</div>


<!--end of css div-->


  </div>
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

And here is my css code:

```
*
{
padding: 0px;
margin: 0px;
    text-align: left;
}

body
{
background: #F9F9F7 url('images/a1.gif') repeat-x;
font-size: 11px;
font-family: "trebuchet ms", helvetica, sans-serif;
color: #8C8C73;
line-height: 18px;
}

a
{
color: #FF7800;
text-decoration: underline;
}

a:hover
{
text-decoration: none;
}

sup
{
font-size: 0.5em;
}


p
{
margin-bottom: 14px;
text-align: justify;
}

img.picA
{
position: relative;
top: -2px;
background: url('images/a47.gif') no-repeat;
width: 76px;
height: 74px;
padding: 8px;
}

img.picB
{
position: relative;
top: -2px;
background: url('images/a26.gif') no-repeat;
width: 146px;
height: 75px;
padding: 7px;
}

img.floatleft
{
float: left;
margin: 0px 14px 3px 0px;
}


ul.linklist
{
list-style: none;
}

ul.linklist li
{
border-top: solid 1px #EEEEEE;
padding-top: 5px;
margin: 5px 0px 0px 0px;
}

ul.linklist li.first
{
border-top: 0px;
margin-top: 0px;
padding-top: 0px;
}

#upbg
{
position: absolute;
top: 0px;
left: 0px;
background: #fff url('images/upbg.gif') no-repeat;
width: 747px;
height: 264px;
z-index: 1;
}

#outer
{
position: relative;
width: 747px;
margin: 0 auto;
background: #fff url('images/abg.gif') repeat-y;
}

#inner
{
position: relative;
padding: 13px 30px 13px 30px;
z-index: 2;
}

> #header {
>     background: url ("~/images/a99.gif") no-repeat;
>     position: absolute;
>     width: 202px;
>     height: 92px;
>     color: #fff;
>     padding-left: 20px;
>     top: 14px;
>     left: 32px;
>     visibility: visible; }



#header span
{
font-weight: normal;
}

#header h1
{
position: absolute;
font-size: 23px;
letter-spacing: -1px;
top: 30px;
height: 92px;
}

#header h2
{
position: absolute;
font-size: 10px;
font-weight: normal;
color: #FCE2CA;
top: 51px;
}

#header sup
{
color: #FCE2CA;
}
```

The image is `a99.gif`! The size is right 202x92px.

Hope that you can help me cause I'm really stuck in this part.

Thanks in advance.

Respectfully yours,
Migs

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `~` is not compiled to give the correct directory.

```
background: url ("~/images/a99.gif") no-repeat;
```

change it to

```
background: url ("images/a99.gif") no-repeat;
```

and its work if you have pages on the root dir and not on subdirectories.

The css file is a static file, that not change or compiled by asp.net.

Comment: Amazing! you're right it's a problem on where i locate my image! from app_themes/default/images i change it to app_themes/default only since thats the one i declare on my web.config file.


Thanks a lot man! Thumbs up!